# Dynamic OrderBy expression with bool predicate

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a model class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am currently returning an ordered list (by name) of `MyModel` from database :

```
return await Db.MyModel
    .AsNoTracking()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
```

However, one of the values in database is "N/A" and I am looking to order by some selector whilst leaving "N/A" last, so basically:

```
 return await Db.MyModel
    .AsNoTracking()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name == "N/A)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
```

I created an `IQueryable` extension, but I am getting an error on the `Expression.Call(...)`

> InvalidOperationException: No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> OrderNALast<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, string>> selector)
{
    var expression = source.Expression;
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");

    var left = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
    var right = Expression.Constant("N/A");
    var predicateBody = Expression.Equal(left, right);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(predicateBody, parameter);

    expression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), 
        "OrderBy",
        new[] { source.ElementType, left.Type },
        expression,
        lambda);

    var appendedQuery = (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(expression);
    return appendedQuery.ThenBy(selector);
}
```

Comment: Does this method have an overload that you use? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netframework-4.8

I cannot seem to find one with Expression.Call(Type, string, Type[], Expression, Expression)

Comment: @iSpain17 I am using `public static MethodCallExpression Call(Type type, string methodName, Type[] typeArguments, params Expression[] arguments);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think I see the problem.

In Expression.Call, the third argument requires the static method's **generic type** arguments to call.

`Queryable.OrderBy()` has two overloads:

```
public static System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource,TKey> (this System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource> source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> keySelector, System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<TKey> comparer);
```

and

```
public static System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource,TKey> (this System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource> source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> keySelector);
```

But instead of giving

`TSource` and `bool`

as arguments, you are giving it

`TSource` and `string`

as arguments.

So it should be:

```
expression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), 
        "OrderBy",
        new[] { typeof(TSource), typeof(bool) },
        expression,
        lambda);
```

(Or you can also use source.ElementType for the first type.)

Comment: You mean should `typeof(TSource)` or `source.GetType()`? Neither of them work though.

Comment: source.GetType(), yea, sorry. What error does it give?

Comment: you cannot use `typeof()` on variables

Comment: I got confused sorry :D

Comment: so your post actually gave me an idea of how this all hangs together and I did figure out what was wrong - the type arguments need to be the same as in the func therefore `<TSource, bool>`, I was giving it `<TSource, string>`, so the answer was to give  `new[] { typeof(TSource), typeof(bool) },`

Comment: I'm happy you figured it out, but that is odd, isn't it? How can you give a `TSource` type parameter as first argument for the OrderBy?

Comment: So that looks like it's not the actually `OrderBy(...)` function parameter types, but rather the `OrderBy<TSource, Tkey>` generic type parameters that the `Type []` parameter in the `Expression.Call(...)` needs

Comment: Oh, I see. And the documentation also states that: *An array of Type objects that specify the type parameters of the generic method. This argument should be null when methodName specifies a non-generic method.* I'll edit my answer then.

Comment: Your answer is now correct with minor last thing, instead of giving it `TSource` and `bool`, I was giving it `TSource` and `string`. My primary fault here is not understanding that the type of `<TSource, TKey>` selector that I am passing in is `string` for `TKey` but after I alter the expression to have `==` it, the actual `TKey` becomes `bool`